# Spring boot find autowired on another package

Tags: spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring Boot application which uses some Spring Data Repository interfaces:

```
package test;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private  BookRepository repository;
    . . .
}
```

I can see that the BookRepository interface (which follows here) can only be injected if it's in the same package as the Application class:

```
package test;
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String> {

    public Book findByTitle(String title);
    public List<Book> findByType(String type);
    public List<Book> findByAuthor(String author);

}
```

Is there any Spring Boot annotation I can apply on my classes to be able to find the BookRepository in another package ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use a Spring [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation alongside the SpringBoot [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) and configure a custom base package (you can either specify a list of package names or a list of classes whose package will be used), so for example

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"otherpackage", "..."})
public class Application
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {otherpackage.MyClass.class, ...})
public class Application
```

or since [Spring 1.3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/spring-boot-1.3-release-notes) (Dec. 2016), you can directly write:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {otherpackage.MyClass.class, ...})
public class Application
```

Note that component scan will find classes inside and below the given packages.

Comment: Actually this is outdated. You can do that directly on @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"...", ",,,"})

Comment: Should i add the package as dependency

Answer (score 0):

Good to verify the scopes of classes kept in different packages by using @ComponentScan annotation in Spring boot startup custom class.

Also add @Component in modal classes being used to allow framework accessing the classes.

Example is kept at
http://www.javarticles.com/2016/01/spring-componentscan-annotation-example.html