# How to retrieve a bean dynamically during runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to use a bean that is created during startup and use it during runtime; both classes are stereotyped but are in different packages. I can't for the life of me retrieve redisSession with @Autowired

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "redis")
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "redis.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class RedisSession {
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisSession.class);
private String hostname;
private int port;
private String password;
private StatefulRedisConnection redisConnection;
private RedisClient redisClient;

@Bean
public RedisAsyncCommands asyncRedisSession() {

    RedisURI redisURI = RedisURI.builder()
            .withHost(hostname)
            .withPort(port)
            .withPassword(password)
            .build();
    redisClient = RedisClient.create(redisURI);
    redisConnection = redisClient.connect();
    return redisConnection.async();
}
```

(Separate package)

```
@Component
public class RedisFieldMappers {

    @Autowired
    RedisAsyncCommands redisSession; //redisSession is null
    public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> getColumnDetails(ArrayList idList,
                                                             String redisSetPrefix, Map<String, String> redisMapper,
                                                             String... fieldNames) throws ExecutionException,
                                                             InterruptedException {
     redisSession.hgetall("foo"); //redisSession is null
     }
```

Comment: Are you doing a component scan on the other package? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425016/spring-boot-find-autowired-on-another-package

Comment: @Martin'sRun Hey, that doesn't do anything. even putting it in the same package doesn't fix it. I am able to autowire this bean in another class that is used during startup, but not during this runtime class.