# Spring , No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" after repackaging

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I did simple repackaging and that caused Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue with my s3 cloud.

I have a local S3 compatible server to store videos , using Spring , am streaming the videos directly from my local cloud .

Everything is working as expected until I tried to repackage my classes .

I had one package **com.example.video** with the following classes:

- **S3Config.java** this contain the AmazonS3Client
- **User.java**  A model class
- **VideoController.java** Simple controller
- **VideoStreamingServiceApplication.java** application class

When I created new package **com.example.s3** package and moved both **User.java** and **S3config.java** , i had auto wired issue and that was fixed by using component scan as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30425971/11301941) suggested .
Even after the autowired issue fixed am getting an error when I try to stream .

> **Access to XMLHttpRequest at "http://localhost/9999/recordins/a.m3u8" fom origin 'null' has been block by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the request resource .**

Although I do have the header mentioned in my request , Here is my **VideoController.java**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cloud")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "amazon.credentials")
public class VideoCotroller {
    @Autowired
    private S3Config s3Client;
    private String bucketName= "recordings";
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VideoCotroller.class);
    @Autowired
    User userData;

@GetMapping(value = "/recordings/{fileName}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamVideo(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String fileName) {
        try {
            long rangeStart = 0;
            long rangeEnd;
            AmazonS3 s3client = s3Client.getAmazonS3Client();
            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            System.out.println("Fetching " + uri);
            S3Object object = s3client.getObject("recordings", fileName);
            long size = object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength();
            S3ObjectInputStream finalObject = object.getObjectContent();        
            final StreamingResponseBody body = outputStream -> {
                int numberOfBytesToWrite = 0;
                byte[] data = new byte[(int) size];
                while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = finalObject.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
                }   
                finalObject.close();
            };
            
            rangeEnd = size - 1;
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
                    .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
// HERE IS THE ACCESS CONTROL ALLOW ORIGIN
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(size))
                    .header("display", "staticcontent_sol, staticcontent_sol")
                    .header("Content-Range", "bytes" + " " + rangeStart + "-" + rangeEnd + "/" + size)
                    .body(body);
            //return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error "+ e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }}
```

If I restore the packages to one , as it was before everything is working fine .

**MY QUESTION** : Why repackaging caused this issue , any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: 1 thing I find weird is that you have `@ConfigurationProperties` on your controller, which is propably also the culprit. Moving those files around (and if they have annotations as well) might influence binding leading to `null` or different proprties. Which propablu lead to an exception leading to a 400 response without CORS. So I would suspect the error line somewhere as well, you want however the full exception stacktrace so to see whats wrong.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment , is there any suggested why on how can i debug this ?  as am new to web , all i can do is send requests , my gradle ( java) console give no error nor exception when i try to stream , that why the error mentioned above is from the browser console when i try to stream .

Comment: There is nothing because you are catching everything and write to system.out instead of properly logging the exception.

Comment: Got it , thank you .